# CiscoIPPhoneExecute->ExecuteItem->URL and Dial commands

Tags: xml, ip, cisco

I am trying to automate dialing a conference call from my Cisco IP desk phone.

I have everything up and working, my phone is receiving commands and executing them. I am just having a little issue getting it to do things in order. Currently I have two separate execute commands Dial Number & Dial Code.

How can I combine the two into one XML command.

I want to do things in this order.

```
Dial Number
Wait 4 Seconds
Dial Code
```

**Dial Number**

91866000000

Wait 4 Seconds - **,,,,**

```
XML=<CiscoIPPhoneExecute><ExecuteItem URL="Dial:91866000000,,,,"/></CiscoIPPhoneExecute>
```

**Dial bridge code**

```
XML=<CiscoIPPhoneExecute><ExecuteItem URL="SendDigits:6020197#"/></CiscoIPPhoneExecute>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
XML=<CiscoIPPhoneExecute><ExecuteItem URL="Dial:91866000000,,,,6020197#"/></CiscoIPPhoneExecute>
```

Works